# Missing configuration for Application File(s)

Tags: configuration, servicenow

I'm new to ServiceNow and have been following the Learning Path on the Developers site. I created a Jakarta Instance and have been making my way through the tutorials. However, I have been consistently running into problems where I am missing configuration options when creating application files. I can't properly set up UI Policies, Events, Notifications, etc. because I'm missing specific options like being able to write scripts and more. I have switched to the "Advanced View" in the "Related Links" but to no avail. The account is an Administrator account and has not been modified at all since the creation of the Instance. Is there something I am missing? Other developers following this track with me currently do not have the same problems so I'm wondering if its account specific or something with configurations. I've attached my Notification file; even in Advanced View, it is missing "Send When" and "Advanced Condition" script.
An example of options not loading: [Notification Application File Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic4QS.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO!.  Take a look at this post on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   Revise your post so it is more likely to be answered and less likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you are under the *Advanced* view for these sections.

These should be there for you, **Send when** and **Advanced condition** are under the *When to send* tab within the *Advanced* view.

If you don't see these under the *Advanced* view, you should be able to manually add the fields using the *Form Designer*.

Take a look at the documentation at [Form design](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-servicenow-platform/page/administer/form-administration/concept/c_FormDesign.html).

In short

- Go to your instance and go to **Settings Gear** > **Developer** and change **Application** to *Global*

[image]

- Right click the header and go to **Configure** > **Form Design**.

[image]

- Verify you've selected the **Advanced** view

[image]

- Drag the missing fields to the form.

[image]

- Click **Save**
- Change the **Application** back to the one you are working with

Comment: The Form Design becomes red and won't let me add in the "Send when" field nor anything else.

Comment: @PandaJohn You'll need to switch your selected _Application_ to be **Global**, I'll update the answer.

Comment: For a brief moment it worked... then somehow reverting back to the scope of the application reverted the Advanced View back to match the default. Somethings wrong with the PDI, my account settings, or something...